# How to build a conditional command in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

Currently, my task looks like this:

```
- name: Create snapshot
  command: nodetool -u foo -pw bar snapshot
```

The `-u` (username) and `-pw` (password) are credentials to use `nodetool`. However, not all environments have authentication for `nodetool`. In case they don't have authentication, then I would need to use the task without `-u` and `-pw`, like:

```
- name: Create snapshot
  command: nodetool snapshot
```

I don't want to have two playbooks (one for authentication required environments, and one for without it). So I'm looking for something of the sort:

```
- name: Create snapshot
  command: nodetool [IF(auth_required){-u foo -pw bar}] snapshot
```

With `auth_required` being a boolean variable in my vars file. How can I do something like this in Ansible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to create the variable `my_command` with the module `set_fact` and use the `ternary` filter to branch control flow. For example

```
$ cat playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        my_command: "{{ 'nodetool' ~
                        auth_required|bool|ternary(' -u foo -pw bar ', ' ') ~
                        'snapshot' }}"
    - debug:
        var: my_command
```

gives

```
$ ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e 'auth_required=false'
    "my_command": "nodetool snapshot"

$ ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e 'auth_required=true'
    "my_command": "nodetool -u foo -pw bar snapshot"
```

Test it. Then use the command

```
- name: Create snapshot
  command: "{{ my_command }}"
```

Comment: I had to use `pre_tasks` instead of `tasks`, but worked otherwise. Thanks!